# Add to cart notice on Product Archive template doesnt work outside customizer

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

I am currently making a webshop, and I noticed that when I add a product to cart via a page that uses the Product Archive template, no notice appears, only a button that leads to the shopping cart appears next to the product.
However, when I add a product to the cart on the exact same page while I'm within the customizer, or via a page that uses the Single Product template, it works as expected, and the notice shows up on top of the page.
I use the "Archive Products" element from Elementor Pro to show the products on the page that uses the Product Archive template, and everything is up to date.

Am I missing something here?
I've already searched Google for quite some time now, and unfortunately I couldn't find anything about this problem.

Comment: This is normal as the behavior is different for Ajax add to cart and normal add to cart…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Wait, so that's that refresh that I see while in the customizer?
Okay, if that's normal, is there any way how I could make it always display the "Added to cart" notice?

Comment: The added to cart notice is only showed on normal add to cart when page reloads and can't be done on Ajax add to cart as the page doesn't get reloaded.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Okay, so basically, there's no way to get the notice to work outside of the customizer?